# Callback function on domain, but redirect to localhost

Tags: php, callback, push, pull

We send a request to a third party server. That server returns it to our domain, such as: `https://www.ourdomain.com/callbacks/script.php`

We then process the response. However, we are still testing. How can we have the callback push to our localhost for development? Currently the only solution we can come up with is writing a script on localhost to pull the response from our domain.

Comment: There's not enough detail here to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  A flow diagram of both situations ("real" and "development") would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve this would be to override the IP address in your hosts file (`/etc/hosts` or `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc`):

Change

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost www.ourdomain.com
```